# Unity3D Hex Grid neighbor search with radius

Tags: unity, grid, tiles

I am trying to develop a small Game with a Hex Grid. I need to find the Neighbors of one Hex Tile in a specific radius.

Here is a screenshot of my Problem: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/kxpt9e)

I followed this awesome tutorial along and implemented some of the systems presented here: https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

```
public GameObject[] GetNeighbarsInRange(Vector2 pos, int range) {

    List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();


    int min = -range, max = range;

    for (int x = min; x <= max; x++) {

        for(int y = min; y <= max; y++) {

            for(int z = min; z <= max; z++) {

                if (x + y + z == 0) {

                    Vector2 newPos = getVector2Coord(new Vector3(x, y, z)), newTilePos = new Vector2(pos.x + newPos.x, pos.y + newPos.y);
                    tiles.Add(getTile(newTilePos));

                }

            }

        }

    }

    return tiles.ToArray();

}

public Vector2 getVector2Coord(Vector3 pos) {

    int x = (int) pos.x, z = (int) pos.z;
    int newX = x, newZ = z + (x - (x&1)) / 2;
    return new Vector2(newX, newZ);

}

public Vector3 getVector3Coord(Vector2 pos) {

    int x = (int) pos.x, y = (int) pos.y;
    int tileX = x, tileZ = y - (x - (x&1)) / 2, tileY = -tileX - tileZ;
    return new Vector3(tileX, tileY, tileZ);

}
```

Here you can see my Neighbor calculation and my Cube to Offset Coords and my Offset Coords to Cube Functions. My Grid is based on the Offset Coord System, I am saving my Grid in a 2D Array and when I search for neighbors I convert them into the Cube Format. My Problem is for the even cols its working fine but for the odd cols, it is not. My Question is how can I fix this?

It is btw. the same if I increase the radius to 2 instead of 1.

Kind regards,

Alex

(Sorry for my bad English I am from Germany:D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot to convert your center tile to cubic coordinates before trying to add cubic offsets to it:

```
public GameObject[] GetNeighbarsInRange(Vector2 pos, int range) {
    // Add this line to the top of your method.
    var centerCubePos = getVector3Coord(pos);

    List<GameObject> tiles = new List<GameObject>();
```

...then later down, make sure you're adding your offsets in cubic coordinates, where the math all works out uniformly. Convert only the *final* result back to offset coordinates.

```
    var cubePosOffset = new Vector3(x, y, z));
    var newTilePos = getVector2Coord(centerCubePos + cubePosOffset);
    tiles.Add(getTile(newTilePos));
```

---

Also, a note on efficiency:

```
for x...
   for y...
       for z...
           if(x + y + z == 0)
           ...
```

Here you're looping over \$(2 \cdot range + 1)^3\$ cells and skipping most of them, to find just \$3 \cdot (range)\cdot (range + 1) + 1\$ results that you actually want - a cubic amount of work for a square number of results. At a radius of 2 you're checking 125 cells for 19 actual hits. At 3 you're checking 343 cells for 37 hits.

We can do this much more efficiently.

One small change would be:

```
for x...
   for y...
       // Once we know x & y, there's only one z that can satisfy 
       // x + y + z == 0, so just set it directly instead of looping again:
       z = -x - y;
       // Reject out-of-range zs calculated this way.
       if(z < min || z > max) 
           continue;
```

Now we're doing only a square amount of work, though we still generate some coordinates we have to skip (at a radius of 2 we search 25 cells for 19 hits, at a radius of 3 we search 49 cells for 37 hits).

Much better, but we could go further if we wanted to and skip no cells at all, by [using the technique described as "Spiral Rings" on the Red Blob Games site](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#rings-spiral).

Answer (score -1):

You can get neighbor search with radius alghoritm from my fog of war method:

```
private void UpdateFogOfWar() {
    var playerCell = tilesGrid.WorldToCell(this.transform.position);

    for (int y = -viewRadius; y <= viewRadius; y++) {
        for (int x = -viewRadius; x <= viewRadius; x++) {
            if ((x * x) + (y * y) <= (viewRadius * viewRadius))
                fogOfWarTilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(playerCell.x + x, playerCell.y + y, playerCell.z), null);
        }
    }

    UpdatePathFindingGridTable();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a method for a square grid, not the cubic coordinate hex grid OP is using. The squares aren't needed to do a radius check in hex space.